# Is this bad programming style?

Tags: ios, objective-c

To check if an **Label** contains a specific **String** in English or German I check if it contains it with the following code and if it contains it I update the image:

```
- (void)checkIfInstructionContainsString{
    if ([stepLabelTop.text containsString: @"left"] || [stepLabelTop.text containsString:@"Links"]) {
        navigationInstructionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"turn_left"];
    }
if ([stepLabelTop.text containsString: @"right"] || [stepLabelTop.text containsString:@"Rechts"]) {
        navigationInstructionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"turn_right.png"];
    }
if ([stepLabelTop.text containsString: @"up"] || [stepLabelTop.text containsString:@"Hoch"]) {
        navigationInstructionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"];
    }
...
}
```

And in **updateInforamtions** method I call it at the end

```
   [self checkIfInstructionContainsString];
```

Why is this bad? Is it better to write it directly into the **updateInformations** method?

Comment: Are you sure you want to set the image to "turn_left" if "right" or "up" is found in the step label?

Comment: It is just there for showing some code.. updated..

Comment: I would definetly prefer the extra method to check the label text. But - depending on your needs - I would maybe write a a mapping function that maps the label to an image name. It would return the image name, and then you set the image outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily bad programming style to extract logic into separate methods (usually this is even considered good programming style).

However, there are other issues that might come up with the code you posted:

- i18n: (UI)Labels are for displaying stuff. This means they are (or at least should be) localized. Now imagine you add for example a French translation. You'd have to add the French words to your checks.
- Multiple logical branches / order of execution: Think about what happens if your text is `@"up left"` ;-)
- Strings are expensive: This is a bit a more technical point, but strings aren't the cheapest thing to work with. Checking an int or enum is much cheaper performance-wise.

I assume you have some kind of model object inside your `updateInformations` method. If said model object contains information about the step (e.g. an enum), you could use code like this:

```c
// -> Definition of the enum used by the model
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyStep) {
    MyStepLeft,
    MyStepRight,
    MyStepUp,
    MyStepDown
};

// Your `updateInformations` method
- (void)updateInformations {
    MyModel *model = /* ... */;
    // ...
    self.navigationInstructionImage.image = [self imageForStep:model.step];
    // ...
}

- (UIImage *)imageForStep:(MyStep)step {
    switch (step) {
    case MyStepLeft: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"turn_left"];
    case MyStepRight: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"turn_right.png"];
    case MyStepUp: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"];
    case MyStepDown: return [UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"];
    default: return nil;
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** This is just my approach to this. There are certainly other approaches that achieve the same and are also considered good programming style.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of approaches that makes this cleaner and better. But there are two quick fixable issues here:

1. It is almost always a bad practice to decide based on an UI element.
2. You can make it a function to extract the logic:

```
- (NSString *)imageForInstruction:(NSString *)instruction {
    if ([instruction containsString: @"left"] || [instruction containsString:@"Links"]) {
        return @"turn_left.png";
    } else if ([instruction containsString: @"right"] || [instruction containsString:@"Rechts"]) {
        return @"turn_right.png";
    } else if ([instruction containsString: @"up"] || [instruction containsString:@"Hoch"]) {
        return @"up.png";
    } else {
        return @"UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```

And then call it like:

```
    navigationInstructionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: [self imageForInstruction:stepLabelTop.text]]; // <- Here you should NOT pass `stepLabelTop.text`. Instead, try to send the corresponding data model.
```

**Note that** It is better to convert it to an enum somehow and switch on that.

Comment: Well, you _also_ decide on an UI element, you just get the value _outside_ of the function instead of inside.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't know the model's name. I have added a little comment about that.